# Does using binary numbers in code improves performance?

Tags: binary, numbers

I've seen quite a few examples where binary numbers are being used in code, like 32,64,128 and so on (for instance, very well known example - minecraft)

I want to ask, does using binary numbers in such high level languages as Java / C++ help anything?

I know assembly and that you would always rather use these because in low level language it overcomplicates things if you go above register limit.

Will programs run any faster/save up more memory if you use binary numbers?

Comment: Erm, *all* numbers are binary.

Comment: Do you mean powers-of-two instead?

Comment: Well, duh. There are registers in PC 16 bit architecture. One register can hold max up to 65535 if I remember correctly. If you want to add two numbers that are below this one, its piece of cake. However, if numbers are higher than these than you have run into a big problem, which costs extra ~200 lines in assembly. That's what this question is all about, how high level languages handle these situations.
@Makoto yes, I do mean powers-of-two

Comment: registers are 32 bit or 64 bit in todays desktops. Or do you have an 16 bit computer?

Comment: Is your question about constants? or about the type/size of integer variables?

Answer (score 2):

As with most things, "it depends".

In compiled languages, the better compilers will deduce that slow machine instructions can sometimes be done with different faster machine instructions (but only for special values, such as powers of two). Sometimes coders know this and program accordingly. (e.g. multiplying by a power of two is cheap)

Other times, algorithms are suited towards representations involving powers of two (e.g. many divide and conquer algorithms like the Fast Fourier Transform or a merge sort).

Yet other times, it's the most compact way to represent boolean values (like a bitmask).

And on top of that, other times it's more efficiency for memory purposes (typically because it's so fast do to multiply and divide logic with powers of two, the OS/hardware/etc will use cache line / page sizes / etc that are powers of two, so you'd do well to have nice power of two sizes for your important data structures).

And then, on top of that, other times.. programmers are just so used to using powers of two that they simply do it because it seems like a nice number.

Answer (score 1):

There are some benefits of using powers of two numbers in your programs.  Bitmasks are one application of this, mainly because bitwise operators (`&`, `|`, `<<`, `>>`, etc) are incredibly fast.

In C++ and Java, this is done a fair bit- especially with GUI applications.  You could have a field of 32 different menu options (such as resizable, removable, editable, etc), and apply each one without having to go through convoluted addition of values.

In terms of raw speedup or any performance improvement, that really depends on the application itself.  GUI packages can be *huge*, so getting any speedup out of those when applying menu/interface options is a big win.

Answer (score 1):

From the title of your question, it sounds like you mean, "Does it make your program more efficient if you write constants in binary?" If that's what you meant, the answer is emphatically, No. The compiler translates all your constants to binary at compile time, so by the time the program runs, it makes no difference. I don't know if the compiler can interpret binary constants faster than decimal, but the difference would surely be trivial.

But the body of your question seems to indicate that you mean, "use constants that are round number in binary" rather than necessarily expressing them in binary digits.

For most purposes, the answer would be no. If, say, the computer has to add two numbers together, adding a number that happens to be a round number in binary is not going to be any faster than adding a not-round number.

It might be slightly faster for multiplication. Some compilers are smart enough to turn multiplication by powers of 2 into a bit shift operation rather than a hardware multiply, and bit shifts are usually faster than multiplies.

Back in my assembly-language days I often made elements in arrays have sizes that were powers of 2 so I could index into the array with a bit-shift rather than a multiply. But in a high-level language that would be hard to do, as you'd have to do some research to find out just how much space your primitives take in memory, whether the compiler adds padding bytes between them, etc etc. And if you did add some bytes to an array element to pad it out to a power of 2, the entire array is now bigger, and so you might generate an extra page fault, i.e. the operating system runs out of memory and has to write a chunck of your data to the hard drive and then read it back when it needs it. One extra hard drive right takes more time than 1000 multiplications.

In practice, (a) the difference is so trivial that it would almost never be worth worrying about; and (b) you don't normally know everything happenning at the low level, so it would often be hard to predict whether a change with its intendent ramifications would help or hurt.

In short: Don't bother. Use the constant values that are natural to the problem.

Answer (score 0):

The reason they're used is probably different - e.g. bitmasks.

If you see them in array sizes, it doesn't really increase performance, but usually memory is allocated by power of 2. E.g. if you wrote `char x[100]`, you'd probably get 128 allocated bytes.

Comment: This is misleading, memory is usually aligned to 8 byte regions, but but this is not always the case, and if you're using integers in your array, it is already aligned because an int is a full word size.

Comment: @drew212 I'm not talking about alignment.

Comment: Then what exactly are you talking about? When memory is allocated and padding is added it is due to alignment. Most current CISC systems aren't restricted by this anymore, but it is still faster to align the memory, this is why it is done. Do you have a reference/source to what you're talking about?

Answer (score 0):

No, your code will ran the same way, no matter what is the number you use.

If by binary numbers you mean numbers that are power of 2, like: 2, 4, 8, 16, 1024.... they are common due to optimization of space, normally. Example, if you have a 8 bit pointer it is capable of point to 256 (that is a power of 2), addresses, so if you use less than 256 you are  wasting your pointer.... so normally you allocate a 256 buffer... this same works for all other power of 2 numbers....

Comment: Careful. I know under the Android platform I've seen my multiplies be made into barrel shifts because they were convenient powers of two.

Comment: Yes, for calculation this is always true... but not always you care about this in high level languages.... so I (personal opnion), don't think this is a concern today.... but in the past (or low level languages), it was a must! But, shifts are useful no matter the time!

Answer (score 0):

In most cases the answer is almost always no, there is no noticeable performance difference.

However, there are certain cases (very few) when NOT using binary numbers for array/structure sizes/length will give noticeable performance benefits. These are cases when you're filling the cache and because you're looping over a structure that fills the cache in a such a way that you have cache collisions every time you loop through your array/structure. This case is very rare, and shouldn't be preoptimized unless you're having problems with your code performing much more slowly than theoretical limits say it should. Also, this case is very hardware dependent and will change from system to system.